# Combining IF formulas in Excel with variable ranges

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm a beginner here. I'm looking to essentially run formulas down in a separate column taking metrics from another column into the formula. Since each month of data is 4000 rows long, The range upon this formula will change from month to month.

The formula in Excel looks like this, and I want to replicate it in VBA with using variable ranges.

```
=IF(H15>=PERCENTILE($H$15:$H$628604, 0.95), H15, 0)
```

I came up with this:

```
Range(NewRangeU).Formula = "IF(" + NewRange2 + ")" >=(PERCENTILE(" + NewRangeU + ", 0.95)"
```

I essentially don't know how to combine the two formulas in VBA.

```
NewRangeU = M4624:M9209
NewRange2 = M4624
```

So the formula in each cell going down the column should be:

```
=IF(M4624>=PERCENTILE($M$4624:$M$9209, 0.95), M4624, 0)

=IF(M4625>=PERCENTILE($M$4624:$M$9209, 0.95), M4625, 0)

 =IF(M4626>=PERCENTILE($M$4624:$M$9209, 0.95), M4626, 0)
```

and so forth.

I know how to add variable ranges inside VBA, what I don't know how to do is combine Variable Ranges with multiple Formulas that includes a condition. I haven't been able to find this answer from my search.  The suggestion from the moderator on my original post didn't help with the question.

The suggestion doesn't work below.

```
Range(NewRangeU).Formula = "=IF(" & NewRange2.Address(False, False) & ")">=(PERCENTILE(" & NewRangeU.Address(False, False) & ", 0.95)"
```

I've also tried combining them into a string which also doesn't work.

```
String1 = "=IF(" + NewRange2 + ">="
String2 = "PERCENTILE(" + NewRangeU + ", 0.95)"
String3 = String1 & String2
'Range(NewRangeU).Formula = String3
```

Comment: That fact that you didn't understand the solution and couldn't apply it does not mean that it is a wrong solution. Even the [syntax highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYHKa.png) on this very website is telling you where the problem is. `NewRangeU.Formula = "=IF(" & NewRange2.Address(False, False) & " >= PERCENTILE(" & NewRangeU.Address(True, True) & ", 0.95), " & NewRange2.Address(False, False) & ", 0)"`. Obviously, provided that `NewRange2` and `NewRangeU` are defined `As Range` and set to `Range("M4624")` and `Range("M4624:M9209")` respectively, like shown in the duplicate.

Comment: Understood GSerg,  Unfortunately - Haven't figured out the correct way to write it - since I have a conditional >= in the formula in addition to two formulas, with two variable ranges.  Thanks for sharing the link.  I'll continue working on a solution then post it if I can figure it out.

Comment: I posted the solution right above.

Comment: For those who need a solution for this kind of problem - I essentially figured it out by doing it in two steps.  The solution creates two columns within the spreadsheet referencing variable ranges.   Range(RangeU).Formula = "=PERCENTILE(" + RangeF + ", 0.95)"   and then on a separate line,  Range(NewRange3A1).Formula = "=IF(" + NewRange2FA1 + ">=" + NewRange2FB1 + "," + NewRange2FA1 + ",0)"